# Fabric Group - List of hosts to Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

Using Fabric2 you can create a group to execute commands either serially or threaded.

```
g = ThreadingGroup('192.168.101.5', '192.168.101.10', user='username', port=22, connect_kwargs={'password': 'password'})    
g.run('uptime')

# Returns:
# {<Connection host=192.168.101.10 user=esp>: <Result cmd='uptime' exited=0>, <Connection host=192.168.101.5 user=esp>: <Result cmd='uptime' exited=0>}
```

If I pass in a list I receive an rsplit error, as a group of strings is expected. I then convert my list to strings, and run again:

```
s = str(servers).strip('[]')
g = ThreadingGroup(s, user='username', port=22, connect_kwargs={'password': 'password'})
g.run('uptime')

# fabric.exceptions.GroupException: {<Connection host='192.168.101.5', '192.168.101.10' user=username>: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')}
```

In the latter example the "Connection host" is being merged, and not separated as in the former example. How do I reconcile this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a list as first argument, that won't work. You need to unpack the list:

```
g = ThreadingGroup(*s, user='username', port=22, connect_kwargs={'password': 'password'})
```